# Can't write to external storage

Tags: android, storage

When I open application must be read external and copy all number from contact to that file but when I try always force close.

```
public class anti_spam extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    BufferedReader reader;
    public String[] Number;
    int x=0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //------------------------
        getListNumber();
        File logFile = new File("root/log.txt");

        //Hitung Jumlah isi File
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("root/log.txt"));
                try {
                while (reader.readLine()!= null)
                {
                    x++;
                }
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {}

        //Hapus File Jika Jumlah Kontak Beda
        if (x-1 != Number.length){
           logFile.delete();
        }
           if (!logFile.exists())
           {
              try
              {
                 logFile.createNewFile();
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Berhasil Dibuat", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 //Isi File
                   try
                   {
                      //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
                      BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
                      String[] numTemp;
                      String numBaru;
                      for(int i=0;i<Number.length;i++)
                      {
                          numTemp = Number[i].split("-");
                        numBaru = (numTemp[0]+numTemp[1]+numTemp[2]);
                        if (numBaru.substring(0, 1).equals("0"))
                        {
                            numBaru = numBaru.replaceFirst("0","+62");
                        }
                          buf.append(numBaru + "\n");
                      }
                      buf.newLine();
                      buf.close();
                   }
                   catch (IOException e)
                      {
                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      }
              } 
              catch (IOException e)
              {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
           }}
```

on manifest

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
>     </uses-permission>
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
>     </uses-permission>
> ```

Comment: show crash dump output

Comment: when i try on AVD program not force close log create.. but if i try on smartphone force close.. smartphone can't create ?

Answer (score 0):

please add this in manifest file.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: read contacts already insert and file log.txt just file with create when application created.. i try create log.txt on sd card still force close.

Answer (score 0):

@Dhiren is correct about adding the permission to the manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

But there is more to the problem, so read on....

---

I think you may need to pay more attention to the folders that you are allowed to write to.

Check out this link on [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) about how to do that.

There is also some useful code in these answers:

- [How to save parsed text file in internal/external storage in android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11290602/383414)
- [Can't write to external storage on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11963713/383414)