# How to write (and append) data to text files externally? (test using real device vs emulator)

Tags: android, append, emulation, external, store

First, I used the code below that I wrote with the help from:
[How to save parsed text file in internal/external storage in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289949/how-to-save-parsed-text-file-in-internal-external-storage-in-android)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String string = "nooooon";

        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File directory = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFiles");
        directory.mkdirs();

        File file = new File(directory, "mysdfile.txt");
        FileOutputStream fOut = null;
        try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        try {
            osw.write(string);
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I used emulator to test it, and it worked fine. I can see the new directory and the new file has been created. Now, I am not sure how I can append data to the current file, meaning that each time I press the button the data need to be appended in the next line.

Second, when I use a real device to test it, I cannot figure out where the new directory and file are created. I actually debugged the app and found that the new file is created under /storage/emulated/0/MyFiles/mysdfile.txt , but I cannot actually see the file in the file explorer or on the device. (Also, I gave permission to write) how can I see the newly generated files/directories?

I appreciate your time.