# How to write html file to local storage in android and then read it?

Tags: android

I have an html string:

```
String htmlString = "<h1>Hello World</h1><p>DaParagraph</p>"
```

I want to save it as file.html to internal/external storage and then read it. What should I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289949/how-to-save-parsed-text-file-in-internal-external-storage-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Please save your html which is string response from server in shared
    preferences like this :**

```
SharedPreferences preferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("HTML", "your html string");
        editor.commit();
```

**2. Get this String wherever you want to use :**

```
SharedPreferences preferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context); 
String htmlString=preferences.getString("HTML", null);
```

**3. Convert String to html :**

```
Html.fromHtml((String) htmlString).toString();
```

Happy Coding.!!

Answer (score 2):

Alternative easy option.

You should store that htmlstring to either SQLite database or SharedPreference as string.

and load that string as html in webview

```
String htmlString = "<h1>Hello World</h1><p>DaParagraph</p>";
                webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8","");
```